# weird shading at center

Tags: modeling, shadows

im trying to follow blenderguru's anvil tutorial series but im getting some weird shading at the center. ive noticed in his video the shading is bad just until the moment he gets rid of the curve in the center. how would I make the shading look better while still keeping the curve?

blend file(anvils at various stages): https://pasteall.org/blend/3e6d5a0ba2de4deb868664638bbd22be

[image: anvil]
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by weird shading? have you smoothed it (right click > Shade Smooth)?

Comment: I did. I mean that right at the center you can see a very blatant dark shading which feels out of place.

Comment: you sent 3 versions, are you talking about the object called "spare"?

Comment: yeah, but they all have the same problem. I think its because I have a few poles  close to that area but im not sure.

Comment: Its because of lighting isn't it? why don't you try different lighting?

Comment: maybe make a close-up shot and draw a circle around the weird shading you're talking about, it doesn't seem obvious, maybe it's just the geometry of your object

Comment: oh sorry, hopefully more visible now. but u can definitely see now a dark line kinda thing. maybe I don't know something, pretty new to this.

Comment: this dark line seems perfectly normal and caused by the shape of the mesh and the light.

Comment: yeah, it appears I cant get read of it really,perhaps its because of having only one light it seems like that. thanks everyone for the help!